# Debugging react native app which shows empty screen in emulator and no error on chrome debugger or package console

Tags: react-native

I am learning react native and tried to execute this sample code. I receive no errors in react package manager console nor in chrome debugger tools nor in emulator

But i do not see the output elements either - i only see a blank screen in the emulator. Not able to think of any other ways to debug and need community help

## index.android.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      AppRegistry,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      TextInput,
      Image
    } from 'react-native';
    import Forecast from './components/Forecast';
    
    export default class Learnreactnative extends Component {
    
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            zip: '',
            forecastParams: {
              main: "Windy",
              description: "Dusty Gusty",
              temp: 30.33
            }
        };
        this._handleTextChange = this._handleTextChange.bind(this);
      }
    
      _handleTextChange(event) {
        console.log(event.nativeEvent.text);
        this.setState({
          zip: event.nativeEvent.text
        });
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>
              You input {this.state.zip}. 
            </Text>
            <Forecast
              main={this.state.forecastParams.main}
              description={this.state.forecastParams.description}
              temp={this.state.forecastParams.temp} />
            <TextInput style={styles.input}
                returnKeyType='go'
                onSubmitEditing={this._handleTextChange}/>        
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
      },
      welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
      },
      instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
      },
      input: {
        fontSize: 20,
        borderWidth: 2,
        height: 40,
      }
    });
    
    AppRegistry.registerComponent('Learnreactnative', () => Learnreactnative);
```

## Forecast.js

```
//import
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

// create component
export default class Forecast extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View> 
                <Text style={styles.bigText}>
                    {this.props.main}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.mainText}>
                    {this.props.description}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.bigText}>
                    {this.props.temp} F
                </Text>
            </View>
            );
    }
}

//styles
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bigText: {
        flex: 2,
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    },
    mainText: {
        flex: 1,
        fontSize: 16,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    }
});
```

[Image link: Chrome dev tools + emulator output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugUOY.png)

**Update 1:**

## adb logcat

output from genny motion emulator is as follows

```
11-25 02:09:05.748   448   805 D AudioFlinger: mixer(0xf1d80000) throttle end: throttle time(11)
11-25 02:09:09.354  1234  1234 W EmojiAltPhysicalKeyDetector: onKeyUp() : No connection to text view
11-25 02:09:13.783   754  1289 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.learnreactnative/.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10008 on display 0
11-25 02:09:13.799  2148  2148 I art     : Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-25 02:09:13.805   754  1284 I ActivityManager: Start proc 2148:com.learnreactnative/u0a60 for activity com.learnreactnative/.MainActivity
11-25 02:09:13.837  2148  2148 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.learnreactnative/lib-main
11-25 02:09:13.837  2148  2148 I fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.learnreactnative/lib-main
11-25 02:09:13.837  2148  2148 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.learnreactnative/lib-main
11-25 02:09:14.019  2148  2148 I art     : Thread[1,tid=2148,Native,Thread*=0xf3db4a00,peer=0x735ad258,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.learnreactnative-1/lib/x86/libfb.so"
11-25 02:09:14.025  2148  2148 W unknown:React: Packager connection already open, nooping.
11-25 02:09:14.030  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTRenderableViewManager
11-25 02:09:14.031  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupShadowNode
11-25 02:09:14.032  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeShadowNode
11-25 02:09:14.032  2148  2169 D OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
11-25 02:09:14.033  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextShadowNode
11-25 02:09:14.034  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewManager
11-25 02:09:14.040  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewShadowNode
11-25 02:09:14.045  1741  1841 E Surface : getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xdf6b8af0
11-25 02:09:14.052  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDialogPickerManager
11-25 02:09:14.055  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode
11-25 02:09:14.057  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager
11-25 02:09:14.064  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDropdownPickerManager
11-25 02:09:14.066  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollViewManager
11-25 02:09:14.070  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageManager
11-25 02:09:14.084  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ReactModalHostManager
11-25 02:09:14.085  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ModalHostShadowNode
11-25 02:09:14.088  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager
11-25 02:09:14.090  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarShadowNode
11-25 02:09:14.092  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextManager
11-25 02:09:14.096  2148  2148 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe995faf0, tid 2148
11-25 02:09:14.097  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextShadowNode
11-25 02:09:14.099  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollViewManager
11-25 02:09:14.102  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager
11-25 02:09:14.104  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager$ReactSliderShadowNode
11-25 02:09:14.105  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager
11-25 02:09:14.106  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager$ReactSwitchShadowNode
11-25 02:09:14.107  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageViewManager
11-25 02:09:14.107  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageShadowNode
11-25 02:09:14.107  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputManager
11-25 02:09:14.111  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputShadowNode
11-25 02:09:14.111  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager
11-25 02:09:14.112  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.toolbar.ReactToolbarManager
11-25 02:09:14.114  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager
11-25 02:09:14.115  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.viewpager.ReactViewPagerManager
11-25 02:09:14.118  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextViewManager
11-25 02:09:14.118  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.webview.ReactWebViewManager
11-25 02:09:14.121  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.recyclerview.RecyclerViewBackedScrollViewManager
11-25 02:09:14.125  2148  2168 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.swiperefresh.SwipeRefreshLayoutManager
11-25 02:09:14.176  2148  2169 D libEGL  : loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
11-25 02:09:14.181  2148  2169 D libEGL  : loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
11-25 02:09:14.193  2148  2169 D libEGL  : loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
11-25 02:09:14.202  2148  2169 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe995fdb0, tid 2169
11-25 02:09:14.213  2148  2169 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-25 02:09:14.254  2148  2169 W EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-25 02:09:14.254  2148  2169 W OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xed6e7ce0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-25 02:09:14.275  2148  2148 W unknown:React: Packager connection already open, nooping.
11-25 02:09:14.397  2148  2172 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "Learnreactnative" with appParams: {"initialProps":{},"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === tr
ue, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
11-25 02:09:14.408   754   779 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.learnreactnative/.MainActivity: +614ms
```

Searched for error messages "unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class" and found few posts where people had faced this issue due to old version of SDK's.

I have double checked using SDK Manager and my SDK's are up to date. Then updated gennymotion as well for collateral Yet the same blank output !

Comment: take a look to the logcat with the monitor tool of android sdk

Comment: @diedu I am running gennymotion emulator so searched and found out that running adb logcat works for genny motion as well. Have edited the question with the logcat output